# assigning a rank based on total sales

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to create a field called “rank”, that ranks each part ID based on total sales, by assigning a sequential number based on total sales, where the higher the total sales, then the lower the rank value. For example, the part ID with the most sales would have a rank value of  “1” and the part ID with the next highest sales would have a rank value of  “2” and the part ID with the lowest sales would rank with the highest number.

If 2 different parts ID’s  have the same total sales, then it is OK if they share the same rank.
Please provide me the SQL to copy and paste

Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
SELECT qry_rank_01.[total sales amount], qry_rank_01.PART_ID
```

FROM qry_rank_01;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is  Ok if duplicate values having a sequentially numbered rank, then the following  function should work

```
SELECT tbl_rank_01.PART_ID, CInt(DCount("total_sales_amt","tbl_rank_01","total_sales_amt >= " & [total_sales_amt])) AS rank, tbl_rank_01.total_sales_amt AS ttl_sls_amt365
FROM tbl_rank_01
WHERE (((tbl_rank_01.total_sales_amt)>0))
ORDER BY CInt(DCount("total_sales_amt","tbl_rank_01","total_sales_amt >= " & [total_sales_amt])), tbl_rank_01.total_sales_amt;
```